# how to replace word document to presentation in drive

Tags: google-drive-api

i am able to do sync files from my system to Google drive and vise-versa.
i wan to know is there any way to change file mime Type and content using Google-api-php-client.
in simple words i have uploaded a word document to drive and now i want to replace this file with presentation.

when i tried this i got 500 internal error. i can catch this exception and then instead of updating a file can create a new file but 
it maybe the case that i received this exception due to any other reason and then it will result in duplication of files in drive.

is this actions is allowed and this is possible in Google drive???

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Following snippet works fine and converts a plain text file into a png one. Existing file had a `text/plain` mime-type. If the mime-type you want to convert to is unknown, that may be a problem.

```
$mimeType = 'image/png';
$file = $service->files->get($fileId);
$file->setMimeType($mimeType);

// Update the existing file.
$output = $service->files->update(
  $fileId, $file, array('data' => '...', 'mimeType' => $mimeType)
);
```